# Sci-fi book with 7 foot tall black humanoid aliens, that invade Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

The book has 7 foot tall black humanoid aliens, that invade Earth. I heard about this book and want to read it and maybe make a PC game based on it.

Comment: Do you know ***anything*** about the story, besides that the alien invaders are 7 foot black humanoids? Is the invasion successful? Do the aliens conquer and enslave mankind, or do they exterminate us? How old is the book? What language is it in?

Comment: And what makes the aliens so interesting that you think it would make a good computer game?

Comment: I think the book is from 1970 or 1980.

Comment: To FB in the post I said, I haven't read it yet, with the key word being maybe.

Comment: Not the Overlords, but a good try thanks

Comment: @Worf022: Ah. I figured maybe there was some hook to their appearance or behavior that particularly stuck with you that might help us further clarify which work you're thinking of. Like maybe they have powerful psychic powers, or arrived and started vacuuming up all of the rabbits on Earth, or tried to conquer us by getting us into a longterm interstellar teleportation contract with the default involving the planet.

Comment: If you haven't read it yet, and IF ALLYOU KNOW ABOUT THE STORY IS WHAT YOU TOLD US, how do you know it's not the overlords?

Comment: +1 to FuzzyBoots for "vacuuming up the rabbits"

Comment: Humanoids, user14111 humanoids, look at the pic below.

Comment: floated in the air, no wings may have been telepathic and it did happen on earth.

Comment: @Worf022 Two things. First, "humanoid" is pretty vague; the "-oid" leaves a lot of room for interpretation. Barlowe's overlord doesn't look terribly humanoid, but is still way more humanoid that lots of sci-fi aliens. Second, what you're looking at is just one artist's conception of Clarke's overlords; other artists have drawn more human-like ones.

Comment: Ok my brother is back in town, he is the one who told me about this book. He said they may have had cat like features, he said it was a book not a short story. We know it was not the overlords.

Answer (score 6):

The height and body color both sounds like the Overlords from *[Childhood's End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childhood%27s_End)*, by Arthur C. Clarke.  The don't exactly "invade" Earth, certainly not violently, but they do arrive and in many ways take over the planet.

Here's [Barlowe's](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/940230.Barlowe_s_Guide_to_Extraterrestrials) illustration of them:

[image: Illustration of an Overlord, a insectoid limbed black humanoid creature with a stocky shelled body, long devil tail and large black wings with red inners.]

There is also some reddish on their bodies, besides the black, but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 5):

C. J. Cherryh's [*Foreigner Universe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreigner_universe) has a colony of humans being enslaved, then emancipated and given their own island. The aliens in question are described as "seven foot tall" and "ebon skinned".

You can see them on the cover art.

[image: Cover for the book showing a man in all white clothing with a bag over his shoulder being flanked by two men in all black with black skin with their backs to him]

Comment: Initially, there was peaceful coexistence and then a war (which humans lost) before the two species agreed to geographic separation, but no enslavement.